# "table or view does not exist" but it does

Tags: create-table, oracle12c

```
user1:

    grant select on user1.view1 to user2;
```

grant succeeded

```
user2:

CREATE TABLE user2.table1 as SELECT * FROM user1.view1;
```

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 46

Does anyone know why the `SELECT * FROM user1.view1;` doesn't work for this view, but I can do it for the other views and tables?

Comment: obviously, the view is there

Comment: You should tag your questions with [oracle] for a wider audience, and only add a version-specific tag like [oracle-12c] if it's something that's only relevant to that version, though it doesn't hurt as it could always be new behaviour. Anyway... my presumption would be that you might have spelled something wrong, but as you've changed the names for posting we wouldn't be able to spot that. It's much better to show your exact commands, copied and pasted from wherever you actually ran them.

Comment: Yea, The problem is in underlying tables within the view that user2 doesn't have an acees to.

Comment: `user2` doesn't need to be able to see the underlying tables in the `user1` schema; that's part of the point of using a view.

Comment: is this a cdb environment?

Comment: actually that's what took me to make this work. I had to grant select on underlying tables... I am using Oracle Spatial and Graph - RDF Semantic Graph services so I was using one of the VIRTUAL models instead of table, maybe that's why I had to grant select on them...